# SignalR in SL5 stops working after upgrade to 1.0.1

Tags: c#, signalr

I have a simple `Hub` that was working with 1.0.0-rc2 between my web app and my SL5 application.

After upgrading to 1.0.1, my .Net Winform clients can still connect to the hub, but my SL5 client can no longer connect.

Upon calling Subscribe, I can see the Negotiate call in Fiddler (which returns 200, with what appears to be valid JSON), followed by the hub `Closed` event firing.  The Error event never fires, and then that's the end of it.  There is no attempt to actually connect, at least as far as I can tell in Fiddler.

Any ideas?  Here's my SL5 code, it's pretty simple/straight forward.

```
        hub = new HubConnection("http://localhost/ADE");
        hub.Closed += new Action(hub_Closed);
        hub.Error += new Action<Exception>(hub_Error);
        hub.Reconnected += new Action(hub_Reconnected);
        hub.Reconnecting += new Action(hub_Reconnecting);
        hub.StateChanged += new Action<StateChange>(hub_StateChanged);

        hubProxy = hub.CreateHubProxy(hubName);

        //Removed my hubProxy.On calls for brevity.


        hub.Start().ContinueWith(task =>
                                    // {

                                     //});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this sample](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/12/17/signalr-building-real-time-web-applications.aspx) that is using SignalR1.0.1 and SL5.

To access SL5 client navigate to `http://localhost:18628/SignalR.Sample.SilverlightClientTestPage.aspx`

On Fiddler, you should get these http requests

`http://localhost:18628/signalr/negotiate?noCache=cd92304d-c824-4c91-abdd-e77c8d096b58`

`http://localhost:18628/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=rse-NdoiZ1Hi7riN_beL6J-zrkGMPm1A9p8urTZn_1sTuZVeEzVWayykaN-Km_fmqBoV06D1e7h5fPWl4kgggABs3x7wiItdd8zJKE9FSCjZsYEUQOdFrzAg-WmA7rUx0&connectionData=[{"Name":"SampleHub"}]&noCache=0c4c1fa1-9aa9-409b-acf7-165faa0d699a`

`http://localhost:18628/signalr/send?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=rse-NdoiZ1Hi7riN_beL6J-zrkGMPm1A9p8urTZn_1sTuZVeEzVWayykaN-Km_fmqBoV06D1e7h5fPWl4kgggABs3x7wiItdd8zJKE9FSCjZsYEUQOdFrzAg-WmA7rUx0`

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.  I was able to connect the SL sample to my existing hub, which rules the Hub out as the culprit.  Further investigation showed another developer hadn't used the NuGet package when adding the reference to my SL project, so it was a version difference causing the issue.